# How debug a Flutter test running inside a Docker container

Tags: flutter, docker, remote-debugging, flutter-test

I am following the [Reduce your CI cost using Docker to run local tests](https://www.bam.tech/article/reduce-your-ci-cost-using-docker-to-run-local-tests) article and managed to run my tests inside a Ubuntu docker container. However, I have one test which fails after about 10 minutes of running. Here is the error I see:

```bash
# flutter test test/lib/mobile/services/sync/sync_service_test.dart
12:25 +0 -1: apiSync It should throw an exception if the sync fails [E]
  TimeoutException after 0:10:00.000000: Test timed out after 10 minutes.
  dart:isolate  _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
```

However, this test runs fine in macOS (my machine and in Bitrise CI).

To help resolve this issue, I am trying to find a way to debug this test. Is there a way I can remotely debug a test running inside this Docker container?

This is a copy of my modified Dockerfile:

```
# Need to match the version of Linux your CI is running on
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Prerequisites
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Europe/Paris
RUN apt update && apt install -y curl git unzip xz-utils zip libglu1-mesa openjdk-8-jdk wget libsqlite3-dev

WORKDIR /home/developer

# Download Flutter SDK
ARG flutter_version
RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b ${flutter_version}
ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/developer/flutter/bin"

COPY pubspec.* /home/developer/project/

WORKDIR /home/developer/project

RUN flutter pub get

COPY *.yaml *.json /home/developer/project/
COPY android /home/developer/project/android
COPY assets /home/developer/project/assets
COPY doc /home/developer/project/doc
COPY docker /home/developer/project/docker
COPY ios /home/developer/project/ios
COPY lib /home/developer/project/lib
COPY macos /home/developer/project/macos
COPY scripts /home/developer/project/scripts
COPY test /home/developer/project/test
COPY test_environment /home/developer/project/test_environment
COPY tool /home/developer/project/tool
COPY web /home/developer/project/web

# Run basic check to download Dark SDK
RUN flutter doctor
```

I would like to know the possibility of remote debugging rather than trying to solve the issue for this particular test.

Thanks in advance  !!!